# Arithmetic of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Tags: field-theory

Let $E=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of the equation $x^3+x^2+x+2=0.$

Express $(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha)$ and $(\alpha-1)^{-1}$ in the form $a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c$ with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$.

**My approach:** Firstly, note that $\alpha$ should be irrational by rational root test. The first one can be done easily in the following way:

$(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha)=\alpha^2(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)+\alpha(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=-2\alpha-2.$

But I don't know how to solve the second one. I have tried different approaches but none of them give something useful.

Would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: What you know about $\alpha$ is simply that $\alpha^3 = -(\alpha^2 +\alpha + 2)$.  I don't see how you've used this in simplifying the first expression, but it allows one to eliminate all the cube and higher powers of $\alpha$.  Our ability to reciprocate $\alpha - 1$ depends on the *irreducibility* of the polynomial satisfied by $\alpha$ and on the expression to be reciprocated being nonzero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you divide the polynomial $x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 2$ by $x-1$, you may get something like 
$$
x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 2 = (x-1)Q(x) + R.
$$
Now put $x = \alpha$, which gives $0 = (\alpha-1)Q(\alpha) + R$. Now you may see how to proceed after.

Comment: Indeed, this is nice trick and very simple. But I was doing in the wrong way :( Indeed, we get $x^3+x^2+x+2=(x-1)(x^2+2x+3)+5$ and plug in $x=\alpha$ immediately gives us a result. Namely $(\alpha-1)^{-1}=\frac{-\alpha^2}{5}-\frac{2\alpha}{5}-\frac{3}{5}.$ Done. Thanks a lot! +1